# IE9 width problem

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

http://testing.ipalaces.org/ looks different in IE9 where the 2nd LI in sub-navigation makes the top border. It seems the width it's at now works for every major browser but IE9. If I set it to exactly 3px less, it works good in IE9.

Is this a known bug? can I get around this without doing a conditional IE9 CSS call?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  I don't see any difference between Chrome, FF4 and IE9 on the menu and the float-down submenus.  There is a gap beneath the "Welcome" though.  Can you post an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that without an explicit width, `#sub-navigation li.selected` renders a few pixels wider in IE 9 because of font rendering, interrupting the next floated element. Forcing a width will fix it.

Also, Verdana in bold renders relatively wide so you should consider dropping it from the font-stack.

```css
#sub-navigation li { font:700 16px/1 geneva, sans-serif; }
#sub-navigation li.selected { width:105px; }
```

Comment: Yeah, I know I could just do that but I stated I did not want use conditional IE statements.

Comment: This works for the main page, but please note that each page the width is different for the li.selected. I am looking for a general fix, the current fix right now is to process everything in my header php file and check for IE9 that way, as I do not want any visible IE9 work-arounds.

Comment: The font problem seems to be the issue, but it didn't exist in IE8. I would change the font, but I picked verdana as the main font for a reason, also the brand's site is width out perfect for verdana.

Answer (score 0):

How about text-overflow?

+css:

```
#sub-navigation li span {
white-space: nowrap;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Try this, anyway I don't have IE (Mac rulz) but in my workplace we usually optimize sites for IE too. I'll check it tomorrow if this is not going to work.

Comment: This has no effect in IE9, or any other browser I viewed it in. Which means the problem still exists in IE9

Comment: So you posted an answer without actually confirming it works?

Answer (score 0):

Can I ask, why do you have all the dropdowns featured as a nested list inside the last `<li>` in the navigation?

If it was me, I'd have each dropdown inside it's own list, as a sub-item fo the parent link.
This way, you can inherit the horizontal boundaries of the drop-down item for the parent-item, and it should be more straightforward to match widths.

Also, the code will read more logically, and expand more easily in future.

Comment: I guess because the dropdowns are the "brands" and I felt they should be under the parent-item that makes them drop down. Although not having to define set widths to match the above one is ideal, I will consider this.

Answer (score 0):

You should set a fixed width to all your li's for the submenu depending on the number you want. right now the first list element should be set to width: 107px.

to test it, just add `style="width:107px`" to `<li class="selected">`

Good luck :)

Comment: if the number of menu items does not change, why not just keep the width fixed?

Comment: They do change, navigate through the site.